# Passing C# int array to C++

Tags: c#, arrays, c++-cli

So I'm passing an array I created in C# into a function:

```
options = new int[3];
options[0] = 3;
options[1] = 5;
options[2] = 4;
formatvalue(options);// the function header is: formatvalue(object options)
```

From here it goes through some interfaces and eventually ends up in a c++ project.

In c++ the function header looks something like: 
`formatvalue(System::Object^ value)`

In the c++ function, I just want to read the data. The whole point of passing in an array is so that I don't have to have tons of different arguments for the function. This took some time to figure out as passing in anything other than a variable gave me some very weird values. At first I tried to pass it a struct of ints, but casting a System::Object into anything at compile time was difficult. So finally I ended up with this bit of c++ code that kind of works:

```
int* test;
memcpy(&test, &value, sizeof(value));
int x;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    x = *(test + i);
}
```

What's weird though is when I dereference test, it gives me some weird garbage, that is until I get to *(test+4) where my array starts :D. Here's what the memory looks like:

f8 ae 0b c2 fe 7f 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 (array starts here) 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 04

I thought the address test was pointing to was supposed to be the first value in the array, instead I have 13 bytes of garbage before my array actually begins. Someone was telling me that these 13 bytes might be a [dope vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dope_vector)? This would make sense as the length of my array is 3 and there is a random 3 sitting in there in the first 13 bytes.

So questions:

1. Why is the address of test not the start of the array?
2. Is the first 13 bytes a dope vector?
3. Is my usage of pointers/memcpy correct?

Edit 1: Changed first question.

Comment: Number 3 isn't a question at all

Comment: Seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822882/marshalling-complex-structures-between-c-c ?

Comment: @MatiasCicero Same for 1.

Comment: Well 1 is a question. An off-topic question though.

Comment: If your C++ header contains `formatvalue(System::Object^ value)` then it's C++/CLI not standard C++. If that's the case please edit your question and tag it appropriately.

Comment: @MatiasCicero I rephrased 3 in the form of a question, thank you for you useful and not completely pointless comment!

Comment: 1) You're doing it wrong. 2) Probably. 3) No.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading a book or some articles on C++/CLI, as you'll want to have a fairly good understanding of how managed and unmanaged code and memory behave.

It's not a dope vector and the data at the beginning is not garbage (your program could not run without it!).

The start of the array is actually at 16 bytes and not 13 bytes (see memory alignment). Keep in mind that the memory is stored little-endian on your machine, so 3 would be stored as `03 00 00 00` and not `00 00 00 03`.

Based on the memory you've provided, it looks like you're initializing `int* test` to be the address of the C# array. .NET objects extra overhead to track information type information via a method table pointer. Arrays also have a field that stores the number of elements in the array. In this case:

```
f8 ae 0b c2 fe 7f 00 00 <- Method table pointer (7ffec20baef8)
03 00 00 00 <- The number of elements in the array
00 00 00 00 <- Padding
03 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 <- Array data
```

What you want to do is something more similar to this:

```cpp
array<int>^ arr = /* ... */;

pin_ptr<int> ptr = &arr[0];
int* test = ptr;
```

Take the address of the first element in the array. You also must use `pin_ptr` since a GC could take place and move the array to a different area in memory.

Alternatively, you could look into using P/Invoke instead of C++/CLI. When using P/Invoke, the CLR automatically handles pinning and ensuring that pointers to arrays and other types are passed into the native method properly.

EDIT: I forgot about question 3.

`memcpy` takes a source pointer, destination pointer, and total number of bytes to copy (note that this is different from the number of elements in the array). If `value` is the parameter for `formatvalue`, then `sizeof(value)`, will be the same as `sizeof(void*)`. So, if the source and destination pointers were correct, you would only be copying 8 bytes -- the first two elements of the array.

Your source and destination pointers aren't correct, however. You've defined an `int*` named `test` but are passing the address of `test` to `memcpy`. You would have wanted to allocate memory up front, assign the address of that memory to `test`, and then pass `test` by value to `memcpy` instead of by reference.

Something like this would work:

```
int* test = allocate_enough_space_for_the_array();

array<int>^ arr = dynamic_cast<array<int>^>(value);

pin_ptr<int> ptr = &arr[0];
int* pval = ptr;

memcpy(test, pval, arr->Length * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Finally got it working using your method! Definitely planning on reading up on c++/cli. Thanks man!

Comment: Good answer - I'm quite surprised that the compiler didn't complain about `&value` in OP's code (taking a managed object's address without `interior_ptr` or `pin_ptr` shouldn't be allowed IMO), but I've just checked and to my surprise it compiles this intrinsically broken piece of code :-\