# How to marshal an array of structs from a native dll to a managed application?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke

I'm trying to pass an array of structs from a native dll to a C# application. I have a struct similar to the following:

**C++**

```
#define EXPORT __declspec (dllexport)

struct Window
{
    Window(HWND hwnd, std::wstring const& title, std::wstring& className)
    {
        m_hwnd = hwnd;
        m_title = title;
        m_className = className;
    }

    HWND m_hwnd;
    std::wstring m_title;
    std::wstring m_className;
};

extern "C" {
    EXPORT const Window* EnumerateWindows(int* windowCount);
}
```

And here is the function we're exporting to the managed application:

```
EXPORT const Window* EnumerateWindows(int* windowCount)
{
    std::vector<Window> windows;

    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&windows));

    Window* newArray = (Window*)CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(Window) * windows.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < windows.size(); i++) {
        newArray[i] = windows[i];
    }

    *windowCount = windows.size();

    return windows.size() ? newArray : nullptr;
}
```

Here's the managed code:
**C#**

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Window
        {
            public Window(IntPtr hwnd, string title, string className)
            {
                Hwnd = hwnd;
                Title = title;
                ClassName = className;
            }
            public IntPtr Hwnd { get; }
            public string Title { get; }
            public string ClassName { get; }
        }

[DllImport("WindowEnum", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr EnumerateWindows(ref int size);
```

I want to use it as follows:

```
int size = 0;
var unmanagedArrayOfStructs = EnumerateWindows(ref size);
var managedArrayofStructs = new Window[size];

// Some magical code to marshal unmanagedArrayOfStructs into managedArrayOfStructs

Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(unmanagedArrayOfStructs);
```

My question is, how do I marshal the array of structs? I know that I can use `Marshal.Copy()` with an array of integer values but, that clearly is not going to work in this case.

Comment: Provided you've defined `[StructLayout(...)]` correctly (including any fields that need an explicit `[MarshalAs(..)]`, then `Marshal.Copy()` should work fine :)  PS: I always cringe when I see folks using Microsoft's C++/CLI with .Net.  C# (or even VB.Net) is almost always results in a cleaner, more robust code base whenever you have the luxury of choosing one .Net language over another...

Comment: i think, c# hasn't an unmanaged array type except of fixed size, so you might need to enable unsafe code in c#, than `EnumerateWindows` can return a pointer to the `Window` array, like `private static extern Window* EnumerateWindows(ref int size)`, at this point you can already access the pointer like an array in c# with `unmanagedArrayOfStructs[i]` and could simply iterate and copy the values, but i never had to do this so there might be an easier way

Comment: also, i think [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays) might help you

Comment: @Patrick Beynio: 1) .Net Interop *should* allow access to arbitrarily complex unmanaged array types, as I said above.2) I'd recommend these links: [Marshaling Classes, Structures, and Unions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions), [Marshaling Different Types of Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays) and [Marshalling Complex structures between C#/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822882)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Marshalling Complex structures between C#/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822882/marshalling-complex-structures-between-c-c)

Comment: @paulsm4 all your links handle arrays of fixed size, except for the same link i provided... and that uses PinvokeLib, to archive it... so .Net doesn't seem to support it natively, and the linked SO article is unlikely to answer his question

Comment: You can't marshal this because you can't access the string in C#. You need to redefine the interface.